# A simple question about the dimension of vector subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $V$ be a finite vectorial space. Let $W$ and $U$ be two vector subspaces of $V$ such that $W\subseteq U$ and $\dim(W)=\dim(U)$.

> Can we conclude that $W=U$?

It seemed obvious to me but I can't find a way to show it systematically.

Comment: If $W\subsetneq U$, then $\dim(W)<\dim(U)$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You can take any arbitrary vector in w and write it as a linear combination of basis vectors of w, the basis vectors are linearly independent and hence can be extended to vector of U, since dimension is the same the basis of U is also a basis of W, so U = W.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).